# How can I display a scoreboard on stage for a play?

Tags: arduino, pic, basic-stamp

I am part of the team who makes the scenery for a theatrical play at school. What is needed to be done is to have a scoreboard in the middle of the room, that one will control from backstage. The scoreboard will have two 3-digit numbers, controlled individually. Whenever the score changes, a little irritating sound should ... sound.

What is the easiest, more efficient and cheapest way to do this? I have found how to make the scoreboard (MANY LEDs, some resistors, transistors, shift registers, an external power-source and an Arduino), but I have almost no idea about the rest. What should I do?

I already have the Arduino, a Basic Stamp, a Raspberry Pi (to play the sounds) and a PIC (PIC16C63, but I have no way of programming it)s and an OlinuXino (Yes I am desperate) lying around. I have 3 weeks to finish it. My budget is very low (30 euros). What is the least minimum I need? Where can I buy it?

If you mention a shop, please take into account that I live in Greece, so the e-shop should ship internationally.

PS
After some researching, I ended up to the following configuration: arduino with scoreboard (shift registers,transistors, LEDs,2 AA batteries and some resistors), connected and controlled by RasPi, via serial (via UART, using a CD4050, because arduino's USB wasn't preferred by me :)). A wifi dongle will be connected to RasPi, which will connect to a wireless network. The raspberry pi will be powered by a 5V 1.5A voltage regulator. A small speaker will be connected to audio jack. All this on the middle of the room. Backstage, there will be a wireless modem, used as a hotspot. Now either I from my android smartphone (connected to the hotspot) via an ssh client, or my teacher from her laptop (same configuration) will control the setup. Now I end up with a software related problem (of how to program everything
Flawlessly), which I will soon ask on the correct stack-exchange. Thank you all for your answers and your effort!!!

PS2 this way I am using many items that I have lying around, so the actual cost is 9 dollars, plus 3 dollars for shipping

Comment: Interesting problem. Pretty much any of the development boards you have, could be used to make it work. If you have physical access to run a cable from backstage to the scoreboard, then even better. Please explain what aspect of the project is your stumbling block. Perhaps if there aren't any good answers soon, I'll post up a block-level approach as an answer.

Comment: I was not sure of how I would control the arduino scoreboard from backstage (1), how to control the RasPi to play the sound (2), what would I need to accomplish it (3) and last, where to buy from (4). If you have any suggestions, PLEASE share it...

Comment: What happens when the score changes - is it an increment of either or both of the 2x 3-digit numbers, is it a toally random number change programmed via some random sequence or maybe a decrement or an add. In short, how do the numbers change?

Comment: Remote control could be accomplished via buttons on long wires which carry an optically-isolated current loop. Push a button, and an opto-coupler activates in the device backstage. The button current loop has its own +V and ground.

Comment: @Andyaka In the play, every time the main actor tells a lie, the enemy team gets a point (+1) and when an actor from the enemy team does so, the main actor gets a point. But at the same time, a sound should be heard to indicate the lie. So the maschine is a "lie-detector"

Comment: @Kaz So I should find long wires and use them like so... But there is a possibility that this would be impractical. I have just thought of IR, but I dont know  where to buy an emitter and a reciever

Comment: IR will be unreliable over distances. Have you ever pushed buttons on a TV remote several times to get something to happen?

Comment: What about RF? Still I don't know where to buy

Comment: @ThePhoton, It's a play. Everything is scripted (or is it improv?). One set of numbers per cue.

Comment: @BobbiBennett, but presumably they spec a 3-digit number because they're going to count to at least 100. And if they increment the count once for each lie, then they need all the numbers between 1 and 100. And one set for each of the two "teams" in the play. So they need at least 200 slides. Sounds a lot easier to do in Powerpoint than with a Kodak carousel.

Comment: How about a power point presentation on a projector? When there is enough room back stage, you can even set up the projector there and aim it at white cotton sheet. The light will easily pass a visible image.

Comment: You know, you could ditch the arduino, and connect the shift registers to the RPI directly, if they are 3.3v compatible, or you use level translation (transistors would work)

Comment: This would make things more complicated for me, because i have some arduino experience, while it will be my first time to use RPi on a project. moreover I want to split the job and use RPi as little as possible, for I can find more suport on the arduino community than on the raspberry pi foundation

Comment: You might consider looking into WS2801 LED strips. You can get them off of Amazon, ebay, etc for pretty cheap.

Comment: I'm with Jippie ---- I'd project it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that a convenient way of getting a lot of LEDs for a little money is flexible LED strips. You can put soft diffusing plastic on top of the strips to make the light more even.

You only need the Arduino for driving the score display. Build the LEDs into common-anode assemblies, one per digit, and switch the anode with a P-channel MOSFET and the cathodes with N-channel MOSFETs. You need six P-channel MOSFETs for the top end of each digit, and seven N-channel MOSFETs for the bottom end of each segment (you can tie the cathode of each segment of the same kind together, as you won't be driving more than one at a time.)

To drive the P-channel FETs, you need a small-signal N-channel FET as a pull-down, and a kilo-ohm-size resistor for a pull-up for the P-channel FET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa64MP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a total of 6+7 == 13 digital outs. If you want to keep digital 0 and 1 for serial programming of the Arduino, use the Analog pins as outputs (it works fine!)

The program does this, over and over:

- Set all digit driver pins to 0
- Set all segment driver pins to 0
- Turn on the next digit driver pin (A0..A5)
- Turn on the appropriate set of segment driver pins (say, D7 .. D13)
- Delay 4 milliseconds
- go back

To update the "appropriate segments" for each digit, use a simple serial read poll. Drive the Arduino from the RPi, or a temporarily borrowed laptop.

No shift register needed! (If you have one, fine, you can run the diodes on 100% duty cycle instead of 1/6 duty cycle.)

Btw: The schematic editor built in here uses annoying MOSFET symbols with the arrow pointing differently from the most common symbol that uses three lines into the body. The bottom ones are N-channel; the top ones are P-channel.

After reading the updated question:

The main question is how you control the score in the first place. Maybe you can use a remote "ssh" connection into the Raspberry Pi to set the score, and have it output the score to the Arduino each time it updates. This means you need to write a little program on the RPi side to keep the serial port open and write news scores out. (Each time you open the serial port, the Arduino will reset!)

You need to run either wired Ethernet, or a wireless USB connector, to the RPi to be able to control it from a laptop/computer off-stage. If you don't yet know how to connect to a RPi or other Linux box using sshd (running Putty on the Windows side, or ssh from the Terminal on a Mac) now's the time to learn!

If you don't know how to write a program that opens a serial port and writes scores to it, now's the time to learn as well! (You can easily do this in Python.) There is a little bit of care needed to make sure that the right digit gets updated for each byte you receive from the RPi serial port; a simple protocol where you receive lines like:

```
XXX:YYY<CR>
```

would be all you need. Keep reading into a buffer on the Arduino side, and each time you get a , parse the line to set the scores.

Comment: I am sorry, but I think I mentioned that I had figured the scoreboard out... Please excuse me if I hadn't made it clear in the question, and thank you for answering. I dunno how to control the project overally

Comment: After seeing your clarified question, I added more on the software and integration part. Hope this helps. Btw: I like Digi-Key for components, if you're in the US. Farnell, Mouser, and many others also exist.

Comment: @JonWatte OP has specified in the question that they are in Greece.

Comment: Farnell sells in Europe (they are UK based.)

Comment: I prefer your answer. I have concluded in using arduino to physically control the scoreboard, the Raspberry pi to control the arduino, and I will have a wifi dongle connected to the RasPi, which will be connected to a private hotspot. Via ssh I will control the RasPi from either my phone or a laptop, connected to the same hotspot. This way the only thing I will have to buy is the scoreboard related things and something to connect arduino and raspberry pi together. Could you explain to me further how this will be accomplished?

Comment: All you need from RPi to Arduino is a simple USB cable. Chances are, you already have one. The Arduino then shows up as a serial port on the RPi (I think as /dev/ttyACM0, but could be /dev/USB0 if I remember wrong.)

Comment: My arduino's USB port has a problem and gets disconnected from time to time all by itself

Comment: In a couple of days the project will be ready and I will upload some pictures somewhere!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just get a programmable LED display [much like this one](http://www.instructables.com/id/Communicating-with-a-Pro-Lite-LED-Display-Cable-C), and an audio amplifier and speaker. Hook these up to a PC, and do it all in software. You can play samples through the PC's audio line out to the amplifier to make whatever sound you want, and talk to the display over RS-232 to make it display numbers.

Forget Arduino, custom electronics and so on. This does not have to be an embedded hardware project.

Comment: Nice and simple. But I have two objections. First, how much will the display cost, and second, how will I control it from away?

Comment: You have objections to people's free advice? Once a PC is involved, it can be on a network, and so you can control this thing from another part of the planet, if you're so inclined. The inputs of a PC's RS-232 port can be used as GPIO's for sensing buttons. I have no idea how much the display would cost, but it may be possible to borrow one from some friendly shopkeeper. Or you could use the seven segment one you have. Just use the Arduino to display the digits, but have them come from the PC.  The Arduino doesn't have to be used to play the accompanying sound.

Comment: Sorry, my misuse of vocabulary did its job again. I meant that there are some factors that don't allow me to consider the above answer a choice, such as the fact it will cost more than 10€ (13 $, as much as what the "other" way). Unfortunately, I have no one to borrow a led display from... About the remote controlling, I hadn't considered what you said about networking when I wrote my first comment. And don't get me wrong, I do appreciate his help a lot!

Comment: Edit needed: *your help